# How to get access to file from security-scoped bookmark url in xpc service?

Tags: macos, file-access, appstore-sandbox, xpc, security-scoped-bookmarks

I am creating sandboxed macOS application. I obtain file url from `NSOpenPanel`, create bookmark data and save to data storage. Then I can successfully restore url from bookmark data and access file data from my app.

I also have another target with `XPC Service` in the project, I pass restored url to this target, but I have no access to file from this url when I try to read file from this `XPC Service`.

My base app and `XPC Service` target both have
`com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope`
`com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope`
`com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write`

What should I do to have access to files from restored urls in `XPC Service` target?
AND can I copy or delete file from `XPC Service`?

Base app

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:file.bookmarkData
                                       options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope
                                 relativeToURL:nil
                           bookmarkDataIsStale:nil
                                         error:nil];
[url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
...
[self.connection.remoteObjectProxy getDataFromURL:url
                                        withReply:aReply];
```

XPC Service

```
- (void)getDataFromURL:(NSURL *)anURL
             withReply:(void (^)(NSData *))aReply {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        aReply([NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:anURL]);
    });
}
```

`[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:anURL]` is `nil`